# How to modify a Visualforce error message

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, error-messages, pagemessages

When I update a record from a details page I get the error

> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary

And when I try to update the record from a Visualforce page I get

> Insufficient Privileges

I know both the error messages are explaining the same problem but I want to display the same error message in both places.

Comment: Is the Error that you are getting on the Updating a Record in Detail Page is due to Validation Rule?

Comment: I think it is not the Validation Rule Error, It is due to some permissions to the Visualforce page exposed to the Profiles. So, check for the Profile level permissions and also check for roles...

Answer (score 0):

Both are security related, but it's not explaining the same thing.

The Insufficient Privileges error comes from not having access to the VF page itself.  You can give yourself access to this via whatever profile you are.

The first error message comes from not having access to the specific record, probably due to how your sharing rules are set up.